# Find multiple keyphrases from a text

Tags: php, regex, string

I have keyphrases abc, xyz, pqr, mno, etc. Text - " this text contains abc and mno", want to find whether text contains keyphrase string.
 I am looking for efficient solution. Please find my current code below.

```
<?php
    $content = " this text contains keyphrases abc and mno ";
    $tags    = array(array('key_phrase'=>'abc'),array('key_phrase'=>'pqr'),array('key_phrase'=>'mno'));
    foreach( $tags as $tag ){
        $matches = array();
        preg_match( "/".$tag['key_phrase']."/", $content, $matches );
        if( !empty( $matches ) ){
            echo "key_phrase present ".$tag['key_phrase'];
        }
    } 
?>
```

Comment: strpos is more efficient and less resource consuming.

Comment: This question belongs in [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @transporter_room_3 - http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/127025/find-multiple-keyphrases-from-a-text

Answer (score 1):

This already is pretty efficient, if your goal is to do something for every matching key_phrase.

preg_match returns true, if something is found, so you do not need the $matches.

```
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    if (preg_match("/".$tag['key_phrase']."/", $content)) {
        echo "key_phrase present ".$tag['key_phrase'];
    }
}
```

If you only wanted to know if **any** key_phrase matches, you should combine all of those to one "big" regular expression in the form "abc|xyc". Because that would be more efficient than individual testing.

Comment: Agreed, but keyphrases will increase in future so "abc|xyz" will not be much feasible.

Comment: That depends on your actual use case. It was just a suggestion.